# Joomla 2.5.6 Admin Menu Issues

Tags: menu, components, admin, joomla2.5

Have used Joomla a fair bit, but have ending up taking over a site previously looked after by someone else. It had been recently updated to 2.5.6 from 1.6 and is sort of ok, but there are a few issues I'm finding particularly with the Admin Menus.

1. the extensions manager is missing its sub menu of 'update' 'discover' etc - does anyone have any idea to remedy this?!
2. a couple of components don't exist in the directory structure (admin or components) but are listed in the in the components menu in admin, so if I try to reinstall them it won't add the menu option...(get error saying menu item already exists).  Does anyone know how to clear the menu options from admin so I can reinstall the components properly?

its a bit of a mess but I haven't the time to start from scratch on this site as its already been highly customised!

Any help much appreciated - as I say I'd be familiar enough with joomla but setting up from scratch without all the mess!

Many thanks
Clare.

Answer (score 0):

For question # 2 you need to use phpmyadmin, or a similar tool and remove the offending components from the xxxx_extensions table. xxxx is a random 3,4, or 5 character string which was created during installation.

Also check the xxxx_menu table for menu items from these components.
Usually admin menu items appear in the "menu" menus.

WARNING! be extremely careful when hand editing your SQL tables. You can completely destroy your site, if you make a mistake. NEVER do a "drop" nor an "empty" with the tool.

As to question #1, I have not seen this behavior. Have you tried an update? or reloading Joomla over your current site? (If you do this, be sure to backup your site! We  use Akeeba backup to do this)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.  for #2 tried this and was able to reinstall - but now the phocagallery admin menu option has disappeared - even though the install seemed to go ok.  for #1 after running a backup I reinstalled 2.5.6 but that sub menu is still missing - most odd :/